# Possible to have pulses with constant voltage?

Tags: voltage, automotive, pulse

tl;dr: I'm asserting that you cannot have constant voltage pulses in a dc circuit. The pulses will be variations in potential or current that some appropriate device picks up. I think I found misinformation on a car forum.

I'm wondering how a car tachometer works. On [this](https://ls1tech.com/forums/pcm-diagnostics-tuning/96783-who-can-explain-how-tach-signal-wire-works.html) LS1 engine forum there is a discussion. "Mr_Dude1" says that :

> the LS1 tach signal looks like . . .just shy of 5v square wave, 4 pulses per every TWO revs. that is, 2 pulses per rev. like a 4 cyl car.
>
> it is not a varying voltage... the frequency (how close the little
>   bumps in the pic are to each other) is what changes.

He attaches a picture of a square wave pattern with no axis labels, so I'm not sure what is pulsing. I think there must be electrical pulses, which are either voltage or current, but I think these types of pulses are inextricably linked due to ohm's law. I have to do some surgery on the wirebundle from the ECU of my car to get at the tach wire, so I though I'd ask you guys first what's going on here.

I don't think I can use a multimeter to test this. If the tach wire is 12V on the car, I suspect that the multimeter will read either 0, 6, or 12V (or some other whacky value) depending on the algorithm used for computing voltage. I think an oscilloscope would be the proper tool here.

Comment: I would guess the tach signal is output from a https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotary_encoder of some description hall/optical etc

Comment: Yes it is possible to generate voltage pulses of fixed amplitude. This is how essentially every digital logic circuit in existence works. Ohm's law is a rule for resistors only, not for other kinds of devices.

Comment: The voltage level of the pulses is 'constant' in the sense that it's either a fixed 'constant' voltage or it's 0 - and nothing in between. No information is being transferred by the voltage level of the pulses. The information is all contained in the *timing* of the pulses. A 'scope is definitely the correct tool for the job here.

Comment: As brhans suggests a scope is the ideal tool, but most multi-meters also have frequency measurement as well

Comment: Your question would probably be better phrased as "How do car tachometer pulses look like and how to measure them?"

Comment: @brhans, that's the answer I was looking for, thanks! Photon, I understand how binary logic works. I guess if I were in charge of all the nomenclature I would call it discrete voltage and not fixed voltage. Or bounded discrete voltage or something. Or fixed voltageS.

Comment: @Wesley, I guess  I know what they look like, I just wanted to verify the vertical axis on the square wave plot was voltage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tachometer on some *very old* cars, which are not equipped with ECU/ECM, works in a similar way. This is before early 80's. Some of the cars in the trasition era mid 80's to mid 90's with simple fuel system also connect the tacho in a similar manner.

**Method 1** - get the signal from the **alternator's winding**

This signal is taken from one of alternator's windings on the AC side, before its rectifying diode. Without a load this signal would be sine wave, but having the very low resistance car battery the upper *rounded* part of the sine wave is flattened. So you get something near a square wave, or to be more accurate - a trapeze wave. Dependancy between this frequency and actual crankshaft rotation speed is not equal for all cars - it depends on number of windings of the alternator and ratio between diameters of crankshaft's pulley and alternator pulley.

**Method 2** - get the signal from the **ignition coil** switch - petrol only, mostly with mechanical ignition

This method applies only to petrol engines and mostly when their ignition is controlled with a mechanism, not electronics. This is before ECU/ECM or in their first years. A signal is taken from the low voltage alternating side of the ignition coil. This signal's ratio is 2 pulses for each crankshaft turn for a 4-cylinder engine or 3 pulses for a 6-cyl engine. This is because the full 4-stroke cycle completes in 2 crankshaft turns, so glowing all plugs sequently till getting back to the first one takes 2 crankshaft turns. Signal shape will be like thin pulses (<5% duty cylce) with most of time positive and active pulse - pulled down to zero.

**Method 3** - **crankshaft sensor** signal

This method is trasitional while moving from electromechanical engine control to fully electronic control. The crankshatf position sensor signal is passed both to ECU/ECM and to tachometer. It's shape is more likely to be as thin pulses with a very low duty cycle - 1% or less. Ratio is 1:1.

**Nowadays**

Modern petrol and diesel cars have crankshaft position sensor and camshaft position sensor for the ECU to manage the engine properly and it is the ECU/ECM's job to send the correct signal to the tachometer. This signal is a digital comunication from ECU to tacho's chip and then this chip drives a servo- or stepper- motor to turn the pointer (or displays animation on LCD).

*That's what I've got from my experience. Please feel free to correct me where needed.*

Comment: Thanks for this great information, but I'm afraid it doesn't answer the really stupid question I was asking. You mentioned pulses, signals, digital communication, and various wave forms! I just wanted to know what is the signal/pulse/communication/wave? I guess it is voltage which goes back and forth between 0V and 12V(or 5V, I'm not sure yet). Thanks for this interesting information and I will look to see what mechanism my truck uses to send the information!

Comment: @JulianCienfuegos yes, it is voltage changing from one value to another through time. Y-axis is voltage, X-axis is time. The actual min/max values depend on many things. If it is based on some standard protocol (as CAN - for digital communication between car modules) it is strictly defined. Otherwise it depends on the exact module (ECU, tacho, alternator, sensor,...) manufacturer (like Bosch, GM, Visteon, etc.).